# Protecting directories on a Apache web server by directory name string match?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-auth

Using Apache, is there a way to protect all items beneath directory names that contain a certain string?

For example, if I have this structure:

```
wwwroot-->
  project1-->
    docs-->
        xls
        doc
          private_docs-->
            txt
        txt
    private-->
        pdf
        doc
  project2-->
    docs-->
        log
        txt
```

Is it possible to user password protect all directories that contain the word "private" ?

Answer (score 2):

It sure seems like you need to place your authorization configuration in either a [LocationMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#locationmatch) or [DirectoryMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch) container.

The match expression might look something like `^/.*/private.*`.

Comment: See this similar question.  http://serverfault.com/questions/118917/reference-the-matched-directory-inside-an-apache-directorymatch-directive